# Why html code in chrome devtools and html code parsed by jsoup are different?

Tags: java, html, google-chrome-devtools, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract information about created date of issues from HADOOP Jira issue site(https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HADOOP/issues/HADOOP-16381?filter=allopenissues)

As you can see in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxX6h.jpg), created date is the text between the time tag whose class is live stamp(e.g. `<time class=livestamp ...> 'this text' </time>`)

So, I tried parse it with code as below.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class CreatedDateExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HADOOP/issues/HADOOP-16381?filter=allopenissues";
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements elements = doc.select("time.livestamp"); //This line finds elements that matches time tags with livestamp class
        System.out.println("# of elements : "+ elements.size());
        for(Element e: elements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }   
    }
}
```

I expect that created date is extracted, but the actual output is 
**# of elements : 0**.

I found this is something wrong. So, I tried to parse whole html code from that side with below code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class CreatedDateExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HADOOP/issues/HADOOP-16381?filter=allopenissues";
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements elements = doc.select("*"); //This line finds whole elements in html document.
        System.out.println("# of elements : "+ elements.size());
        for(Element e: elements) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }
}
```

I compared both the html code in chrome devtools and the html code that I parsed one by one. Then I found those are different.

***Can you explain why this happens and give me some advices how to extract created date?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to get elements with "time" tag, and use select to get time tags which have "livestamp" class. Here is the example:

```
Elements timeTags = doc.select("time");
Element timeLivestamp = null;
for(Element tag:timeTags){
  Element livestamp = tag.selectFirst(".livestamp");
  if(livestamp != null){
   timeLivestamp = livestamp;
   break;
   }

}
```

I don't know why but when I want to use .select() method of Jsoup with more than 1 selector (as you used like time.livestamp), I get interesting outputs like this.

Comment: And also, I inspected the page and IMHO it's too hard to land created date with only one .select() query. There are lots of elements with class "timestamp". I advice you to use getElementsByAttributeValue() method of Jsoup. For ex, if you want to get Created date time, you have to use Element spanElem = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id","created-val").first() --> get the Created span, and after that  Element createdtimeElem = spanElem.selectFirst(".livestamp") will works properly.